# How to use SendKeyEvent to send combination key to GeckoFX

Tags: c#, combinations, geckofx

In a recent project I'm using the current version of GeckoFX to embed a browser in my C# application.

The browser has a function on it to send key presses to the browser window.

I can send a key to *GeckoFX extended browser*, but now I wanna send combination keys but the code not working:

Here's my code

```
txtLog.AppendText("Pressing `Ctrl+Enter`...\n");
webBrowser1.Window.DomWindow.Focus();
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keydown", 17, 0, 0, true);
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keydown", 13, 0, 0, true);
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keypress", 13, 0, 0, true);
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keyup", 13, 0, 0, true);
webBrowser1.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keyup", 17, 0, 0, false);
```

It doesn't press Ctrl+Enter key at any time.

How do I make it work on the new versions of GeckoFX?

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you want to achieve with those keystrokes, I suppose there is a better way (simulating pressing keys is not a good one)

Comment: @Bartosz: Excuse me, but this's my company project so its idea couldn't be shared. I found another way to do this without SendKeyEvent. I used SendMouseEvent with X-Y coordinates. Thanks for your support :)

Comment: Ok, that's no problem. I wasn't interested in high level goal of this secret app, just what exactly do you want to achieve with a click (e.g. "I wanna click a button" or "I wanna fill in text box"). Sorry to say that, but most likely you're doing it wrong, and it will probably be unreliable....

Answer (score 1):

I never used the geckofx `WindowUtils` but if it is on a windows form app you can use `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys` class to send keystrokes to an element. You can add combination keys too. I'm not sure of the syntax but maybe `SendKeys.Send("^({ENTER})")`.  See

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

You might have to put focus on the browser first - `geckoWebBrowser1.Focus()`;

Comment: Thanks for your helping, BUT I don' t wanna Focus window every time need type somethings, even if it's very annoying action when minimize

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but this is NOT the first time this has been asked in the GeckoFX forums, or on the issues in the bit-bucket project, and since I've just had to scratch and scrape all round the internet to find this info, I thought I'd answer it here for those who are looking for it as this SO post actually comes pretty much top in every related search on the subject.

No one in the issue tracker, GFX project or anywhere else I looked seems to be answering or maintaining any of these queries.

In the latest build of GeckoFX60 the old "SendKeyEvent" interface (As used in the OP's original question) has been deprecated, not only has it been marked as deprecated but if you try to use it, you'll get an exception telling you to use the "**nsITextInputProcessorCallback**" interface.

This interface is not documented in the samples, or on the project WiKi or anywhere, all that exists are a few deeply buried issues that give a hint as to it's use and a C# definition in the project sources for the "Mozilla IDL interface" of the same name.

Since I had an older app to upgrade, I had to work out a way of doing this myself, I have a replacement SendKeyEvent call working as follows:

```
private void SendKeyEvent(int keyCode, bool alt, bool ctrl, bool shift)
{
  var instance = Xpcom.CreateInstance<nsITextInputProcessor>("@mozilla.org/text-input-processor;1");
  using (var context = new AutoJSContext(_browser.Window))
  {
    var trans = instance.BeginInputTransaction((mozIDOMWindow)_browser.Document.DefaultView.DomWindow, new TextInputProcessorCallback());

    var keyEvent = context.EvaluateScript(
        $@"new KeyboardEvent('',
               {{ key: '', 
                  code: '',
                  keyCode: {keyCode},
                  ctrlKey : {(ctrl ? "true" : "false")},
                  shiftKey : {(shift ? "true" : "false")},
                  altKey : {(alt ? "true" : "false")} }});");

    var kd = instance.Keydown((nsIDOMEvent)keyEvent.ToObject(), 0, 1);
    var ku = instance.Keyup((nsIDOMEvent)keyEvent.ToObject(), 0, 1);
  }

  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
}
```

To make this work you also MUST define a class as follows

```
  public class TextInputProcessorCallback : nsITextInputProcessorCallback
  {
    //NOTE: This never actually gets called by the input processor shite for doing a simple key press in SendKeyEvent above
    //but the nsi processor crashes if you don't create and specify the damn thing!!!!  basically, DO NOT REMOVE IT
    public bool OnNotify(nsITextInputProcessor aTextInputProcessor, nsITextInputProcessorNotification aNotification)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("TestCallback:OnNotify");
      return true;
    }
  }
```

As my comments in the class state, this never seems to get called, or used by GeckoFX in any meaningful way, BUT if you don't include it somewhere in your code, and use it in the BeginTransaction call in your key press the Mozilla NSI processor xpcom kernel crashes and/or goes ape and causes problems.

To use it, is simple, keyCode is a browser VK_xxxx code so for example if you want to send the "1" key to the browser that has

```
VK_1 (49)
```

So

```
SendKeyEvent(49, false, false, false)
```

Will cause the browser to see that keypress

**NOTE:** The new method will ONLY generate a KeyDown & a KeyUp , NOT a KeyPress, however if you read the notes on MDN for the DOM key event class you'll see that KeyPress is being deprecated and phased out.

If your "WebCode" in the page is only hooking the "KeyPress" event in javascript, then do be aware that the newer key sending method will NOT BE PICKED UP by your web page, you will need to adjust the page code to look for KeyUp/KeyDown events.

The old method (With a compatible method signature) for completeness, I have defined in my code as follows:

```
private void SendKeyEvent(int keyCode, bool alt, bool ctrl, bool shift)
{
  //TODO: combine modifiers
  var modifiers = 0;
  _browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keydown", keyCode, 0, modifiers, true);
  _browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keypress", keyCode, 0, modifiers, true);
  _browser.Window.WindowUtils.SendKeyEvent("keyup", keyCode, 0, modifiers, true);
}
```

I still need to work out the flag values/order for the modifiers, it'll be on MDN somewhere but I don't need it right now so I'll look it up when I have time.

This works for me in the WindowsForms code I'm using, do beware also that it IS thread sensitive, if your responding to an event that's NOT on the same thread as the UI holding the GeckoFX browser control, you WILL get an exception when you call it, a properly placed Invoke check and call however will solve that problem.